# C# Winform: How to restrict a user to go into particular TabPage in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro

I am Creating a sample Inventory windows form application in which if the dictionary of quantity is empty then user should not be allowed to go into sales tab.

> I am using metro design and material skin mix up to design my application I have posted a code sample below which works in case of simple winform control but not working in case of metro and material design.

Code Sample

```
//check if selected tab is sales tab 
if (tcmain.SelectedTab == tpSales)
{
  //check if our cart is empty or not 
  if (Globals.qty.Count == 0)
  {
     //show error msg
     var diaEmptCart = MessageBox.Show("There Are 0 Products in Cart", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     //set selected tab as purchase 
     tcmain.SelectedTab = tpPurchase;
  }
  else
  {
     //or show the products available in cart for sales 
     //populate combo box with them 
     cmbPro.DataSource = new BindingSource(Globals.qty, null);
     //set key as display member 
     cmbPro.DisplayMember = "Key";
  }
}
//check if selectedd tab is tab purchase 
if (tcmain.SelectedTab == tpPurchase)
{
  if (Globals.qty.Count == 0)
  {
    //if yes, setting cart empty
    pbCart.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\ThE PrOgRaMmEr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\simpleInventory.cs.MUI\simpleInventory.cs\Resources\crt_empty.png");
  }
  else
  {
    //if not, setting cart full
    pbCart.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\ThE PrOgRaMmEr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\simpleInventory.cs.MUI\simpleInventory.cs\Resources\crt_full.png");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle tab selecting event of the control. Try this:

```
private void tcmain_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
      //Change whatever you want
      if (tcmain.TabPages[e.TabPageIndex] == tpSales && Globals.qty.Count == 0)
            e.Cancel = true;
}
```

But the question is why you're even displaying the tab. I'd recommend not to create tabs which aren't required.

Comment: then shall i remove the method                                                   private void tcmain_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)  as such your solution works

Comment: I would recommend that you disable the tabpage when you load your dictionary and it is empty. So the user don't get a Messagebox. Whereever you load your data check if sales are empty and when call tpSales.Enable = false;

Comment: @Jaydeep, if you dont want to do any specific task on selected tab changed then you may remove this event. Also please mark it as answered if it is usefull

Comment: [sebi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1463584/sebi) sure man will do [kashi_rock](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1335773/kashi-rock)thanks for the answer